# Calculator only covers a small range of jobs

Tags: discussion, salary-calculator

I just took a look at the salary calculator, and it seems that none of the job descriptions match anything I have ever done despite working in software development and management for 40 years (now retired). For example, where are architecture roles? Systems programming? And why are administrator roles there for a development calculator?

Comment: Its due to the data they have. My job isn't adequately represented either (Unity game/AR/VR development).

Comment: @Draco18s: I would note that the categories here match the set of categories in the StackOverflow Developer Survey as far as I can see. I always struggle with the developer survey :x

Comment: @Draco18s That's under "Game developer" if you're working on the software or "embedded developer" if you're working on the hardware itself.

Comment: @DBedrenko I hadn't even noticed that one in the drop down. I am still amused by the "jobs you might like." Three tagged [sql-server] (of which one is written IN GERMAN for a job IN GERMANY and I'm US based) because "oh you work with C# and C# is usually web and web is usually full stack and full stack includes sql!" ("all photographers are paparazzi" problem) Another couple are tagged [c++] (which I did not include in the technologies I work with) and not also tagged [c#].